# SpeechAzure Cognitive Services

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I deployed the SpeechAzure solution behind the proxy. Therefore, I need to know all the URLs / URIs that the speech azure makes connections to the internet. I have to open the port for those URLs/URIs. Please let me know all of those URLs/URIs. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand Bertrand, why you make -1 here? I googled it and I can't find the ip address for https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-started-speech-to-text?tabs=windowsinstall&pivots=programming-language-python.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not positive what service you mean by "SpeechAzure", but you find the Azure IP Ranges listed at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519.

Comment: Thank you Jenifer. I am building a solution based on:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-started-speech-to-text?tabs=windowsinstall&pivots=programming-language-python

It works using my home desktop but it doesn't work if I deploy it behind the proxy. I am thinking that the azure.cognitiveservices.speech library will connect to the azure resources at some point to get the text. In that case, I have to open the p

Comment: the link you provided doesn't work. It redirects me to microsoft surface

Comment: anybody can help me on this?

Comment: Scroll down past the Surface ad.  Do you see a "Azure IP Ranges and Service Tags – Public Cloud" title and download button?  The download is a json file of the ip addresses for various Azure services.  I'm not 100% positive, but I think you might want the "CognitiveServicesManagement" entry.